# How to attach 3 fields in email body in an android email application

Tags: android, email, android-intent, attachment

Normally email apps only have an EditText where the app copies what the user writes and pastes it into the email client's body.
I have 2 more fields, specifically 2 TextViews that contain Longitude and Latitude coordinations and I also want those to appear inside the email body.
I'm using this code, but only the latest String appears in the mail (lat)

```
            Intent emailIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
            emailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, new String[]{"email@email.com"});
            emailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "subject");
            emailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, message);
            emailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, longi);
            emailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, lat);
            emailIntent.setType("message/rfc822");
            emailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, imageUri);
            startActivity(Intent.createChooser(emailIntent, "Choose an Email client"));
```

Comment: You need to combine the message with the coordinates and just put `EXTRA_TEXT` one time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Construct a string with all three fields.

```
String text = "";
text += message + "\n" + longi + "\n" + lat;
emailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, text);
```

Of course use text and formatting as you like.

Answer (score 2):

The second and third times that you call `putExtra()` for `Intent.EXTRA_TEXT`, you are replacing the previous value.

Instead, create *one* string that contains the *entire* message, including the `longi` and `lat` values, and use `putExtra()` for `Intent.EXTRA_TEXT` on that one string.